# Change Owner of Accounts Created by Portal Users

Tags: customer-portal, partner-portal, default-value, experience-cloud, defaults

Recently we've been getting the error message that "you cannot create a Customer Portal user associated with an account owned by a Partner user". As I understand this, it is a limitation that prevents an account where the owner is a Portal User to have Contacts associated with it that are Customer Users.

Unfortunate as this is, I'm trying to understand if there is a way to make Accounts, when created via Apex Classes in a Portal, to default to being owned by a user who is a System Administrator instead of the Portal user who caused the Account to be created. This way, when attempting to add users to the account this conflict will not happen.

I've developed a possible solution in the form of a Before Insert apex trigger (below) , but I'm wondering if there is another alternative that may be as simple as a setting I'm missing. I found the instructions to set the default owner of records created by guest users, however these users are not guest users since they are logged in portal users.

```
trigger AccountTriggerBI on Account (before insert) {

    Profile sysAdmin = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
    User defaultUser = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE ProfileId =: sysAdmin.Id AND IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
    
    for(Account a : trigger.new) {
        a.OwnerId = defaultUser.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use Flow or Apex to achieve this.  A flow is probably easier to build and maintain.  Be sure the automation only runs when a community user is creating an account, because right now your Apex will fire for any user.

Comment: Is a Flow or Apex the only solution though? It seems like a major system flaw that a portal user could create an account and then that account wouldn't be able to be used for additional portal users in the future.